# duplicate counter entres in perfmon log

Tags: perfmon

I've been recording several counters in perfmon and one of them occasionally duplicates itself in the output log file, e.g.:

"COUNTER1","counter2","counter3","COUNTER1","counter4","counter5","counter6","COUNTER1","counter7"

The counter in question (COUNTER1 above) is "\MyMachine\Processor(_Total)\% User Time"

I can't work out why that counter should sometimes appear three times. The counters in the perfmon task are fine i.e. the counter in question is only listed once. There's just something in the execution that's sometimes making it record an additional few times...

Has anybody else come across this? Is this intentional depending on factors within the OS environment?

Comment: Interesting but a bit off topic for SO IMO. Maybe a better fit for Superuser or ServerFault?

Comment: OK, have asked there also. Thanks for input...